# Flowchart for Number of Days Past task

Tags: python, diagram, flowchart

Pretty new to programming. I've got the program to work but struggling to construct the flowchart

Task Instructions

Number of Days Task

Instructions

Create a program that will ask the user for a day, month and year and calculate how many days in that year have passed. For example, if the user
enters 3rd February 2021 (3, 2, 2021), then that is the 34th day of the year. (31 days in January, plus 3 in February).

The program should store the number of days in each month in an appropriate data structure. The number of days is as follows:

January         31 days
February    28 days
March           31 days
April       30 days
May     31 days
June        30 days
July        31 days
August          31 days
September   30 days
October         31 days
November    30 days
December    31 days
January     31 days

Important:

• solve the task by creating a flowchart before coding.
•The program should include, at least, one function with parameters passing in/out
• You may not use any Python date modules/library’s functions
• You must use least one list (days in each month).
• You must make use of at least one function.
• You must make use of good Python variables and naming conventions.
• Leap years must be considered

Constraints:

• Only valid dates – for example 29 February 2021 is an invalid date

I've got the program to work but struggling to construct the flowchart. The program works I'm just struggling with the flowchart part.

`

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, d, m, y):
        self.d = d
        self.m = m
        self.y = y


# store number of days in all months from
# January to Dec.
monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
            31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

# counts number of leap years
# before the given date


def countLeapYears(d):

    years = d.y

    # Check if the current year needs to be considered
    # for the count of leap years or not
    if (d.m <= 2):
        years -= 1

    # An year is a leap year if it is a multiple of 4,
    # multiple of 400 and not a multiple of 100.
    return int(years / 4) - int(years / 100) + int(years / 400)


# number of days between two
# given dates
def getDifference(dt1, dt2):

    

    # count using years and day
    n1 = dt1.y * 365 + dt1.d

    # Add days for months in given date
    for i in range(0, dt1.m - 1):
        n1 += monthDays[i]

    # leap year is of 366 days,
    # Add a day for every leap year
    n1 += countLeapYears(dt1)

    

    n2 = dt2.y * 365 + dt2.d
    for i in range(0, dt2.m - 1):
        n2 += monthDays[i]
    n2 += countLeapYears(dt2)

    
    return (n2 - n1)





dt2 = Date(0, 0, 0)
dt2.y = int(input("input first dates year\n: "))
dt2.m = int(input("input first dates month\n: "))
dt2.d = int(input("input first dates day\n: "))

dt1 = Date(1,1,dt2.y)
print(getDifference(dt1, dt2)+1, "days")`
```